# Regex remove quotes around integers?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

Let's say I have a string "\"Bob\",\"1\",\"Mary\",\"2\"". Is it possible to remove only the quotes around the numbers and not the letters? I've tried look-ahead/behind but the non variable length for look-behind screwed me and I have no idea how to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: In which language do you require a regex?

Comment: using R right now but it can take in perl syntax

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in php:

```
<?php
$in = "\"Bob\",\"1\",\"Mary\",\"2\"";
$out = preg_replace('/"(\d)"/',"$1",$in);
echo $out;
?>
```

in javascript:

```
var $in = "\"Bob\",\"1\",\"Mary\",\"2\"";
var $out = $in.replace(/"(\d)"/g,"$1");
alert($out);
```

my best guess in R: (I am not an R programmer)

```
in <- "\"Bob\",\"1\",\"Mary\",\"2\""
out <- sub("\"([:digit:])\"","\\1",in)
print(out)
```

... here `\\1` is equivalent to `$1` and `[:digit:]` is equivalent to `\d`

to explain the regex

php `preg_replace()` function takes a regular expression as the first parameter in the form of a string, a replacement value as the second parameter in the form of a string, and the source as the third parameter in the form of a string, and returns the modified string after regular expression replacements have taken place.

javascript `.replace()` method operates on a source string, takes a regular expression as the first parameter, and a replacement string as the second parameter. It returns the modified string after regular expression replacements.

In this example, the regular expression is delimited by (starts and ends with) slashes (`/.../`), and matches any digit (`\d`) captured by brackets (`"(\d)"`) and enclosed by quotes (`"(\d)"`). In javascript the `g` flag is used to make replacements global (repeat for all occurances). The captured digit (captured because it is enclosed in brackets) is then referenced in the replacement with `$1` meaning the first captured group. `$0` matches the entire matched string. `$2` would match the second captured group - but there is none in this regex. Anything contained within brackets in regex is a captured group and can be referenced in the replacement by it's index via `$n` where n is it's index. So to put it simply, the regex replaces all occurances of a digit enclosed in quotes with just the digit.

Comment: using R which has support for perl regex.. i saw that $1 syntax before but didn't know what it was/what it was called. could anyone possibly explain how it works?

Comment: @Michael: I see Billy updated his answer; here's some more general information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplace.html